# How Magic functions work with unserialize() in PHP object injection?

Tags: php

I was reading about PHP Object Injection , and i don't understand how magic functions work with this vulnerability, this is my tested code :

```
$sec1=serialize($_GET['ser']);
$sec2=unserialize($_GET['unser']);
class ex
{
public $cmd;
 function __wakeup()
  {
   system($this->cmd);
  }
}
```

Now assume that the url for the script is :

```
http://localhost/unserialize.php?z=O:2:"ex":1:{s:3:"cmd";s:3:"dir";}
```

after this request the "dir" command will work .

My question is , why the value for $sec2 is go to cmd variable on __wakeup() function ?

as i already know, if i need to pass a value for variable i need to do this :

```
$somevariable = $_GET[name of input];
```

but there's no statement like this in my code .

Comment: Are you sure you have posted the details correctly, that your example works, and that you understand what happens? Because as-is I'm pretty sure this code is buggy and would just break. Certainly your example "exploit" is not correct.

Comment: @ConorMancone , oh sorry , now i make it correct , i checkt it now . 
i unnnnnderstandd ! , from the payload i put the right class name and the variable name too with the value , so from this the value go to the right variable on __wakeup() , im right ??